# Serializing an object that was initialized in the main

Tags: java, serialization

I'm trying to serialize an object, gc, through a method within my class.

```
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File("dump.out"));
  ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(f);

  // Write Objects to File
  o.writeObject(gc);

  o.close();  // must close the file or nothing gets written
  f.close();
```

The object gc itself is only created later in my file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    GreenhouseControls gc = new GreenhouseControls();
```

This setup doesn't work because my serialization method cannot find gc.

Comment: If I understand this right, the serialization happens in a separate method outside of `main()`. Do you call your serialization method from `main()` and pass `gc`to it as an argument?

Comment: You can't serailzie an object you haven't created yet. You must have just serialized `null`. The question doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the instantiated `GreenhouseControls gc` to the said method.  If it is not passed to that method it is out of its scope.  Ex:

```
void doSomething(GreenhouseControls gc) {//code...;}
```